# Force browser pass through proxy without previous config (transparent mode) windows

Tags: windows, proxy, squid, netsh

I'm using de [proxyfree](http://www.handcraftedsoftware.org/) by handcrafted software, but i'm in a trouble. I can use normally the proxy by SETTING the browser (at proxies configs) and putting the ip/port. This works fine. But i need to user the proxy without this setting. Like in squid, i need this proxy works like transparent mode (with none browser config by the user browser). I tried put some netsh rules like (listening from a ip/port that shares the internet to the ip/port the receive the internet)

```
portproxy add v4tov4 listenport=80 listenaddress=192.168.137.1 connectport=80 connectaddress=192.168.0.131
portproxy add v4tov4 listenport=8080 listenaddress=192.168.137.1 connectport=8080 connectaddress=192.168.0.131
portproxy add v4tov4 listenport=443 listenaddress=192.168.137.1 connectport=443 connectaddress=192.168.0.131
```

I created 3 proxies listening all these ports (80, 8080 and 443) in 192.168.0.131.

Is is possible to do that? If you have another solution like block ALL internet connection to the user, and just allow connection if the browser pass through the proxy, it's nice to me too.

Answer (score 0):

https://reqrypt.org/windivert.html may serve your needs. You can also just set 192.168.0.131 as a custom gateway.

If you want to do things securely, you need to filter outside of your restricted machine, e.g. on the router.